# outlook security in asp.net webpage

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I used http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Outlook-Send-E-mail-Without-Security-Warning , to finish my first ms access vba app that sends multiple notifications via outlook, without security pop-up.  Now I want to make a WEB BASED version of it.  So, using asp.net & mysql instead of vba & access raises certain questions.

When I comes down to it, what would be the difference of using  (will post link below)  vs installing VSTO runtime to run the outlook module I allready used in my first link?

Would you consider the "add-in" a more robust, integrated, easy approach since it seems I'd otherwise need to put the module of my first link in each users outlook install or am I just completely mistaken or is it a combination of both, please explain...

Answer (score 0):

Click below for

[2nd link of first post , outlook addin](http://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/)